# Unable to load a checkpoint's data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the code from here to learn the text summarization task with transformer model, [It can be found here](https://github.com/rojagtap/abstractive_summarizer/blob/master/summarizer.ipynb)

But the code doesn't provide a way to load a model after training, so It's an inconvenience and I decided to write that function

Here is what I have done:

```
model = Transformer(
num_layers, 
d_model, 
num_heads, 
dff,
encoder_vocab_size, 
decoder_vocab_size, 
pe_input=max_len_news,
pe_target=max_len_summary,
)

input = tf.random.uniform([1, 12], 0, 100, dtype=tf.int32) #create dummy input
enc_padding_mask, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask = create_masks(input, input) # create masks
a = model(input, input, False, enc_padding_mask, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask) # call the model before loading weights

model.load_weights('checkpoints/ckpt-5.data-00000-of-00001')
```

Now, It throws an error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
171         if swmr and swmr_support:
172             flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
--> 173         fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
174     elif mode == 'r+':
175         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

I'm totally new to machine learning and TensorFlow. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [documentation of `tf.keras.Model.load_weights`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Arguments
>
> filepath  String, path to the weights file to load. **For weight files in TensorFlow format, this is the file prefix** (the same as was passed to save_weights).

You only need to pass the prefix, so

```
model.load_weights("checkpoints/ckpt-5")
```

should do the trick.